# How to access Canon CR-50 installed on the system using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing a project which needs to access Canon CR-50 check scanner.
How can I make it work? I have no Idea to begin the coding. I am currently working on Linux(Ubuntu) machine, any solution for Windows or Linux will help me a lot. I am using Laravel framework. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: This isn't really something that PHP would do directly without some major work. My suggestion would be that you start off trying to get a CLI executable that will scan and write the image to disk. You can always set the process running and capture the image from the given path using exec (or alike) functions and file_get_contents. The scanimage command might be a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu Linux you can use the [scan-image](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/scanimage.1.html) command-line interface to manage and control image scanning.

From there within your PHP application you would call the scan-image software via the PHP function [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

See also:
http://www.sane-project.org/source.html

Edit:
Woops, so there does appear to be a front end utility in PHP for the sane-project, that can be found here http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/.

Comment: I have tried `scanimage` but it throws `scanimage: no SANE devices found`. I think Canon CR-50 is not been detected by SANE.

Comment: Connect your scanner via the USB cable and use the sane-find-scanner command. See here for more documentation in relation to Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane.

Comment: @NithilGeorge if you require further help with SANE I would recommend asking at http://askubuntu.com/.